# Problema no envio de formulário para e-mail

Tags: php, formulário, phpmailer, envio-de-email, sendmail

Tenho um formulário que envia os dados digitados para o meu e-mail.
Mas não consigo enviar a cópia para o usuário informado no campo e-mail do formulário.
O que estou fazendo de errado?

**contato.php**

```
<form name="contato" method="POST" action="enviar-contato.php">
            <input type="text" name="nome" autofocus required placeholder="Digite seu nome">
            <input type="tel" name="telefone" required placeholder="Digite seu telefone" id="ddd_tel" class="ddd_tel">
            <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Digite seu e-mail"><br>
            <select name="assuntomsg" required id="assuntomsg">
              <option selected="selected">Selecione o Assunto</option>
              <option value="Dúvidas">Dúvidas</option>
              <option value="Reclamações">Reclamações</option>
              <option value="Sugestões">Sugestões</option>
            </select>
            <textarea name="mensagem" cols="40" rows="8" required></textarea>
            <button type="reset"><b>Apagar</b></button>
            <button type="submit"><b>Enviar</b></button>
        </form>
```

**enviar-contato.php**

```
<?php

//Variáveis

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$assuntomsg = $_POST['assuntomsg'];
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
$data_envio = date('d/m/Y');
$hora_envio = date('H:i:s');

// Campo E-mail
$arquivo = "
<style type='text/css'>
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 100%; border: none; outline: none; font-weight: 300; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;}
body {
margin:0px;
font-size:12px;
color: #858585;
}
a{
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
.titulo {
width: 98%;
padding: 2%;
}
.titulo h2 {
background-color: #88e004;
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: bold;
width: 100%;
padding: 2%;
margin-bottom: 2%;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
font-size: 16pt;
        margin: 0 0 1% 2%;
}
    img {
        margin: 0 0 2% 2%;
    }
.rodape {
width: 100%;
background-color: #88e004;
  padding: 2%;
  color: #ffffff;
font-size: 10pt;
}
h5 {
font-size: 24pt;
color: #88e004;
text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 4% 0 1% 2%;
  text-align: center;
}
h6 {
font-size: 14pt;
color: #88e004;
text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  text-align: center;
}
h7 {
font-size: 10pt;
color: #858585;
}
h8 {
font-size: 10pt;
color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<html>
<div class='titulo'>
<h2>Que legal, $nome. Olha abaixo a confirmação do seu contato.</h2>
    <p><b>Telefone:</b> $telefone</p>
    <p><b>E-mail:</b> $email</p>
    <p><b>Assunto:</b> $assuntomsg</p>
    <p><b>Mensagem:</b> $mensagem</p>

    <h5>Muuuiiitttoooo Obrigado!</h5>
    <h6>Logo responderemos o seu contato.<h6>

    <h7>Este e-mail foi enviado em <b>$data_envio</b> às <b>$hora_envio</b></h7>

</div>
</html>
";

//enviar

// emails para quem será enviado o formulário
$emailenviar = "contato@meusite.com.br";
$destino = $emailenviar;
$assunto = "Contato no Site";

// É necessário indicar que o formato do e-mail é html
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'From: contato@meusite.com.br, <$email>' . "\r\n";

$enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $arquivo, $headers);
if($enviaremail){
echo "<script>window.location='contato.php';alert('$nome, sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso! Estaremos retornando em breve');</script>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, pode mostrar a parte do PHP que faz o envio do e-mail? Acredito que seja nessa parte que esteja o problema. Caso estaeja utilizando o **PHPMailer**, segue a solução que utilizo.

```
<?php 
require_once("PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP

try {
    $mail->Host = 'email-ssl.com.br'; // Endereço do servidor SMTP (Autenticação, utilize o host smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
    $mail->Port       = 587; //  Usar 587 porta SMTP
    $mail->Username = 'email@meuservidor.com.br'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
    $mail->Password = 'senha'; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)

    //Define o remetente
    $mail->SetFrom('email@email.com', ''); //Seu e-mail
    $mail->AddReplyTo('email@email.com', 'Nome'); //Seu e-mail
    $mail->Subject = $subject; //Assunto do e-mail


    //Define os destinatário(s)
    $mail->AddAddress($value);

    //$mail->AddCC('destinarario@dominio.com.br', 'Destinatario'); // Copia
    //$mail->AddBCC('destinatario_oculto@dominio.com.br', 'Destinatario2`'); // Cópia Oculta

    $msg_email = 'Mensagem do E-mail';

    //Define o corpo do email
    $mail->MsgHTML($msg_email);  
    $mail->Send(); 


//caso apresente algum erro é apresentado abaixo com essa exceção.
}catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //Mensagem de erro costumizada do PHPMailer
}
?>
```

Comment: Este é o código completo.
Não usei o PHPMailer.
É melhor?

Comment: @Turkish eu gosto bastante do PHPMailer, acho ele simples e prático.  Veja esse [exemplo](https://www.devmedia.com.br/php-envio-de-e-mail-autenticado-utilizando-o-phpmailer/38380)

Comment: Eu li um pouco sobre o PHPMailer e atribui ao meu projeto. Porém tenho o mesmo problema. Ele envia para o meu e-mail, mas não vai para o destinatário informado no campo email do formulário. Segue meu código abaixo.